# escaping a complete packet read in apache module

Tags: c, loops, performance

According to this site:

```
http://pedrowa.weba.sk/docs/ApiDoc/apidoc_ap_get_client_block.html
```

This function:

```
ap_get_client_block(request_rec *r, char *buffer, int bufsiz);
```

Reads a chunk of POST data coming in from the network when a user requests a webpage.

So far, I have the following core code that reads the data:

```
      while (len_read > 0){
                len_read=ap_get_client_block(r,argsbuffer,length);
                if((rpos+len_read) > length){rsize=length-rpos;}else{rsize=len_read;}
                memcpy((char*)*rbuf+rpos,(char*)argsbuffer,(size_t)rsize);rpos+=rsize;
      }
```

argsbuffer is a character array of length bytes and rbuf is a valid pointer, and the rest of the variables are apr_off_t data type.

If I changed this code to this:

```
      while (len_read > 0){
                len_read=ap_get_client_block(r,argsbuffer,length);
                if((rpos+len_read) > length){rsize=length-rpos;}else{rsize=len_read;}
                memcpy((char*)*rbuf+rpos,(char*)argsbuffer,(size_t)rsize);rpos+=rsize;
          if (rpos > wantedlength){len_read=0;}
      }
```

would I be able to close the stream some way and maintain processing speed without corrupt data coming in?

I already executed ap_setup_client_block(r, REQUEST_CHUNKED_ERROR) and made sure ap_should_client_block(r) returned true before processing the first code above. so that is like in a sense, opening a file.  ap_get_client_block(r,argsbuffer,length). is like reading a file. Now what about an some ap_ command equivalent to close?

What I want to avoid is corrupt data.

The data that is incoming is in various sizes and I only want to attempt to capture a certain piece of data without having a loop go through the entire set of data every time. Thats why I posted this question.

For example: If I wanted to look for "A=123" as the input data within the first fixed 15 bytes and the first set of data is something like:

```
S=1&T=2&U=35238952958&V=3468348634683963869&W=fjfdslhjsdflhjsldjhsljsdlkj
```

Then I want the program to examine only:

```
S=1&T=2&U=35238
```

I'd be tempted using the second block of code. The first block of code works but goes through everything.

Anyone have any idea? I want this to execute on a live server as I am improving a security detection system. If anyone knows any other functionality that I should add or remove to my code, let me know. I want to optimize for speed.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for SO, since it's about the technical details of a specific set of functions in a particular environment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a conceptual question on software development as defined in the [help/on-topic].